# Downgrade wordpress multi site to earlier version

Tags: wordpress, upgrade

I'm having some problem with a custom made plugin since upgrading to the newest wordpress version. I've made downgrades before, so that's not the problem. This, however, is a multi site and I'm uncertain if it makes a difference when making the downgrade? Is it the same or should it be avoided?

And, yes, I know I should probably change the plugin, but it is vital for the site!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not much of a conclusive answer really, but I am fairly certain I have successfully downgraded downgraded a WPMU site in the past (before it was renamed Network Site). Just load `/wp-admin/upgrade.php` as you would normally do. I would strongly recommend you do the downgrade on a development system before performing it on you production site.